# How to perform an Ace in Tennis in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I was playing Tennis in-game, and I saw a stat after a tennis match.

> You can pass an Ace to the other player.

For those who don't know, an [Ace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_%28tennis%29) is a serve in Tennis that is not touched by the receiver, thus winning the point in one swing.

So how can I guarantee that I serve an Ace?

Comment: Shoot your opponent in the head with your pistol before you serve :-P

Comment: @Dom Will that actually count as an ace?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you serve from the left side of your field to the right side, stand at the most left point of the field, aim to the most right side of the other field and try to get the full power.

It's hard to do an Ace, but it is possible. For me, this way is the easiest way!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen aces even in my first tennis match, without any strategy what so ever.
I wasn't even aware that you can aim you ball.

Just hit the ball at the maximum swing and chances are you'll hit an ace.

Answer (score 0):

You can always throw the ball on the opposite direction of your opponent at maximum power. There's how:

People tend to stay in the middle of the court *(god knows why)*, so it's a good idea to wait for him*(her)* to get to his*(her)* position then shoot as far as possible from them. It helps a lot if your shot is strong.